# Get Inner Class Instance status

Tags: java, reflection, inner-classes

Use case is something similar to below code. There is a class(Inner_Demo) inside another class(Outer_Demo). Inner_class will be instantiated upon some condition in the outer class private method.

```
class Outer_Demo {

    public Outer_Demo() {
        test();
    }

   // private method of the outer class
   private void test() {
       Inner_Demo demo;
       if(condition)
           demo = new Inner_Demo();
   }

   // inner class
   class Inner_Demo {

   }
}

main(){
    Outer_Demo outer = new Outer_Demo();

    // Here I need to check is Inner class got instantiated
    // Trying to print the value as below leads to error create 
    // field/constant Inner_Demo in Outer_Demo
    System.out.println(Outer_Demo.Inner_Demo); // outer.Inner_Demo

   /* Storing the created instance to Outer_Demo.Inner_Demo 
   is allowed */
   Outer_Demo.Inner_Demo inst = outer.new Inner_Demo();
   System.out.println(inst);
}
```

I need to test, Is inner class is Instantiated or not. I got to know that calling the inner class in above way is incorrect.

Reflection might have used if the field **demo** in the **Outer_Demo** class's method **test** is not local/ have class level access.
Can anybody help me to understand, Is there any way find inner class status. Any links to subject is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check if an object of that class has been instantiated.

For this task you should declare an `Inner_Demo` field in your `Outer_Demo` class:

```
class Outer_Demo {

    public Outer_Demo() {
        test();
    }

Inner_Demo innerDemo;
         ...
```

Now, each time the object is instantiated, this field must be assigned a value:

```
innerDemo = new Inner_Demo();
```

And finally, when you want to check if the object exists, you just do it like:

```
if (innerDemo == null) {
   //object does not exist yet and has to be instantiated
} else {
   //object does exist and can be used
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I mentioned in the question, the field is local to method & this is for some security reasons.  As you mentioned, if it has class level access, getting value us simple. I can't modify the parent code. Any other way?

Comment: The field is local to method? That is not a field. it's just a reference to the object which is eliminated once you return from the method. If you mean "I don't want to share the object, I just want to know if it exists", then, instead of Inner_Demo field, declare a simple boolean field. And set it to true each time the object is instantiated. The rest is the same. And by the way, if you do not share the object... what's the point of creating it I wonder...?

Comment: “if it exists” makes no sense in this context. Without a reference to the object, the object does not exist. And if the existence of the object has no visible side effect (which the application can test), there is no point in saying that only one object is allowed to exist. Apparently, it does not matter anyway.